# Looping through Beautiful Soup results

Tags: django, beautifulsoup

I have searched for all elements with the tag p as shown below

```
def get_html_content(request):
    import requests
    number = request.POST.get('number')
    USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36"
    LANGUAGE = "en-US,en;q=0.5"
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers['User-Agent'] = USER_AGENT
    session.headers['Accept-Language'] = LANGUAGE
    session.headers['Content-Language'] = LANGUAGE
    html_content = session.get(f'https://sdahymnal.net/sda-hymnal-{number}').text
    return html_content

def home(request):
    result = None
    if 'number' in request.POST:
        html_content = get_html_content(request)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
        result= soup.find_all("p").text
      
    return render(request, 'user/home.html', {'result': result})
```

but I get the error below:

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

please help as I want to pass all elements to the template and show them in stanza form..here is my template code

```
{% for result in result %}
    {{ result }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you please read [ask] and edit your question so it's a [mre]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`soup.find_all('p')` returns list and list doesn't have `.text` method. So, in your `views.py` just remove `.text`:

```
def home(request):
    result = None
    if 'number' in request.POST:
        html_content = get_html_content(request)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
        # Removed .text
        result = [i.text for i in soup.find_all("p") if i.text]
        print(result) # check if this does print anything
      
    return render(request, 'user/home.html', {'result': result})
```

And in your template you can just access it like:

```
{% for res in result %}
    {{ res }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thank you for the response but it is now not printing to the template but when I print to the console it works perfectly

Comment: @WILLIAMOnchuru I don't know what might be causing this but let's change our result in `views.py` and access it easily in template.